# How to insert data into `group` labeled table

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have a database in Postgres that has multiple tables. One of them is `group`. I know that this is a reserved name. The question is how to insert data into that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) you need to use double quotes:

```
insert into "group" (column_1, column_2)
values (42, 'foo');
```